# Valgrind giving error: "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)"

Tags: c, pointers, valgrind

I'm pretty sure I know what this error means. It's pretty self explanatory. But I don't understand why. Especially because THE ERROR POINTS TO LINES 59 AND 61 ONLY. As in the functions `printDictionary` and `menu`. I don't understand why it would work on `loadDictionary`, which takes the same variables as arguments. Any advice?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char **wordArray;   /* declare the dynamic array of strings, not yet allocated.*/

    int capacity = INITIAL_ARRAY_MAX;
    int wordCount = 0;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s inputfile outputfile\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (loadDictionary(argv[1], &wordArray, &wordCount, &capacity) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"    loadDictionary failed! Program terminating...\n");
        return 1; /* already in main() so exit unneccesary.*/
    }

    printf("\n  Finished loading %d words from dictionary.\n", wordCount);

    printDictionary(wordArray, wordCount);   /* Line 59 */

    menu(&wordArray, &wordCount, argv[2]);   /* Line 61 */

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my loadDictionary function. It does initialize the array! Also I just tried addign functions before loadDicitonary and any function before it which has the array as an argument works. So the problem clearly lies in loadDictionary.

```
int loadDictionary(char *inputFileName, char ***array, int *count, int *capacity)
{
    FILE *inputFile;
    char word[WORD_LENGTH];

    if ((inputFile = fopen(inputFileName, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening input file, %s\n", inputFileName);
    return -1;
    }

    *array = (char **)malloc(*capacity * sizeof(char*));
    if (*array == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc of array in loadDictionary failed!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Reading file %s (each . is 5000 words read)\n", inputFileName);

    *count = 0;
    while (fscanf(inputFile, "%s", word) == 1)
    {
        if (*count >= *capacity)
        {
            /*makes new array of double size with contents of original array.*/
            if (doubleArraySize(array, *count, capacity) != 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "Doubling array failed!\n");
            }
        }
        if (insertWord(*array, count, word) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"    Insert returned an error!\n");
            fclose(inputFile);
            return 1;
        }

        if (*count % 5000 == 0)
        {
             printf(".");
             fflush(stdout);
        }
    }

    fclose(inputFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind Log.

```
==6107== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6107== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6107== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6107== Command: ./lab2 105-words.txt output.txt
==6107== Parent PID: 3994
==6107==
==6107== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6107==    at 0x4089E29: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1630)
==6107==    by 0x4091EFE: printf (printf.c:35)
==6107==    by 0x804882F: main (lab2.c:59)
==6107==
==6107== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6107==    at 0x4089E29: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1630)
==6107==    by 0x4091EBE: fprintf (fprintf.c:33)
==6107==    by 0x8048F49: menu (lab2.c:271)
==6107==    by 0x804884F: main (lab2.c:61)
==6107==
==6107==
==6107== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6107==    in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6107==   total heap usage: 110 allocs, 110 frees, 3,197 bytes allocated
==6107==
==6107== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6107==
==6107== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6107== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==6107== ERROR SUMMARY: 210 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: How does `loadDictionary` work? My guess is there is a code path that returns `0`, but doesn't set `wordArray`.

Comment: Which lines are 59 and 61?

Comment: Line 59 -> printDictionary(wordArray, wordCount);


Line 61 -> menu(&wordArray, &wordCount, argv[2]);

Comment: I don't see a conditional jump or move on either of those calls. Can you post the full, exact error message?

Comment: The line numbers in your error aren't matching up with your source code. Please recompile and run `valgrind` again. (Also, you haven't included the source code to the `menu()` function.)

Comment: The second problem is at line 271 in the function `menu()`, which happens to be called from line 61 in `main()`.  You need to diagnose the last line in your code — as opposed to system library code like `printf()` and `vfprintf()` — as the point where the trouble occurs.  You have a number of memory leaks on error paths in `loadDictionary()`; also you don't always close the file stream. As @duskwuff noted, line 59 is not the call to `menu()` as you claimed, but the `printf()` just before it; line 61 is the call to `menu()`.

Comment: I messed around with the code after getting the error. It does point to the functions i mentioned. Both problems seem to be pointing at this line

wordPtr = (char*)malloc((strlen(word)+1)*sizeof(char));

Comment: When debugging "uninitialised value" warnings, the "--track-origins=yes" option is really useful to see where the uninitialised value comes from. Can you add that option and post Valgrind output?

Answer (score 4):

The above [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html) message indicates that somewhere in your program uninitialized variable has been used.

To see information on the sources of uninitialised data in your program, use the option:

> --track-origins=yes

This would help you to track down the root causes of uninitialised value errors in  your program.